# How to change "Search" button text in keyboard of SearchBar in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, searchbar

I use following code for SearchBar control. When user click on SearchBar, it shows keyboard with "Search" button to search in Keyboard. I want to change name of it.

Here is my current code: Xaml

```
<SearchBar Text="{Binding SearchText}" Placeholder="Search" />
```

SS
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a NuGet package called [EntryCustomReturnPlugin](https://github.com/brminnick/EntryCustomReturnPlugin). It allows you to change the text on the done button of an `Entry`.

However I don't think it works with a `SearchBar` out of the box. You will need to either change your `SearchBar` into an `Entry` or write a [custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) (you can use the source code of the [EntryCustomReturnPlugin](https://github.com/brminnick/EntryCustomReturnPlugin), the code will be very similar to that).